# Solving equations with formulas differing results (are they equivalent)

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm trying to solve the equation below and i'm struggling to produce the same answer as then textbook.

\begin{align*}
  L &= \pi(r_1+r_2)+2d \text{ for }r_1 & \text{Subtract }2d\\
  L - 2d &= \pi(r_1+r_2) & \text{Divide sides by }\pi\\
  \frac{L - 2d}{\pi} &= \frac{\pi(r_1+r_2)}{\pi} & \text{Simplify }\pi\\
  \frac{L - 2d}{\pi} &= r_1+r_2 & \text{Subtract }r_2\\
  \frac{L - 2d}{\pi} - r_2 &= r_1 & \text{}\\
\end{align*}

However the answer i'm given is
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a typo; it should be $r_2$ rather thant $r^2$.

Comment: Even still, the answer i've reached is different

Comment: No, it is not:$$\frac{L-2d}\pi-r_2=\frac{L-2d-\pi r_2}\pi.$$

Comment: hmm, ok thanks, I see that $\pi R_2$ is the same as $r_2$ because of the division that is applied thanks. Do you know the method they have used to get the same output as them?

Comment: I think that they thought that it would be more natural to give the answer as a single fraction.